# Magento adds payment and shipping fees to cart totals

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have a problem with a Magento shop.

The default payment option has a fee of 49 SEK. But there is several other payment options without a fee, this one just needs to on top.

The problem is, when i come to the store and add something to the cart it automatically adds those 49 SEK to the totals summary, so if i add products for 200 SEK it says 249 SEK in the cart in the header and as totals in /checkout/cart/.

First i thought this was something specific with this payment module, but i noticed if you choose a shipping method in the cart and returns to the shop. It adds this fee as well.

Is there a way to only show the product totals before checkout?

We are using onepage checkout and a stock theme, but i have tried deactivating both the theme and OPC with no luck.

I guess if there was a way to not set default payment method it would do it, but opposite of shipping methods, there is no way to select blank for default payment method in the settings.

If i change to a payment method without a fee, it works as needed but since the store has a special deal with this payment company, they need to be favored in the checkout :/

Comment: Okay i solved it for the cart summary in the header by using Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); instead of Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();

Comment: The question is how i get /checkout/cart/ to not add fees in its calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote() to get cart on session. And getAllItems() to get the itens from cart.
collectRates() to get the rates for the cart.

Gl On  that

Comment: I thought there was some more fundamental level this should be fixed ad than hacking the templates? Which is what i did for now.. but it feels wrong (:

Comment: What kind of payment method you have? Your payment method is adding fee on your cart without your consent?

Comment: it is a Swedish payment company called Klarna and it is like a downpayment plan and they charge a fee for that. The fee should be there and i can control it in admin, i only wish it didn't appear before the actual checkout since the user can avoid it by choosing another payment method.

Comment: but if user change the payment method still geting the Fee from the Klarna?

Comment: no, but since klarna is the default/first option it adds this fee to the summary before the user had a chance to select option. i know this is quite weird that it needs to be the default alternative but still cant show it's fee before checkout. but it is their request... i guess if i could make "Klarna" appear on top but no payment option is selected by default (how it works with shipping), it would do it.

Comment: I think its no way to make a order without payment method. You need active something like "checkmo" to be the first "default" option and don't add the Fee, or make your own payment method to behave like you want. Or you can take a look on http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total?facebook=1 its a custom module to add fee and discount and you can make something about your fee. It was very useful for me.

Comment: Thank you will have a look. But honestly i did a quite dirty solution now and used the subtotal before any fees as subtotal and hide the rest..

Comment: when we work with magento, the "dirty solution" sometimes is the best way ;)

Comment: uhm atleast the only reasonable way. but i have also had among the wost experiences ever taking over current magento projects... so i feel sad for the next guy ;)